# Add View Programmatically ignore padding

Tags: java, android

I am adding a view to my relative layout with has 16dp padding all around

```
View blackView = new View(RestaurantActivity.this);
                    blackView.setMinimumHeight(height);
                    blackView.setMinimumWidth(width);
                    blackView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    blackView.setAlpha(0.5f);
                    rl.addView(blackView);
```

and this view is also has that padding, but I want it to fill the full screen and ignore the padding, how could this be done programmatically?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I tried this

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)blackView.getLayoutParams();
                    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                    int dpAsPixels = (int) (-16*scale + 0.5f);
                    params.rightMargin = dpAsPixels;
                    params.leftMargin = dpAsPixels;
                    params.bottomMargin = dpAsPixels;
                    blackView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But got this error

```
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.james.duss.ResturantActivity$1.onClick(ResturantActivity.java:156)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post full Logcat error

Comment: @dieter_h see addition

Comment: Null pointer in `ResturantActivity.java` line 156 `onClick` event

Comment: Your question is about Padding ignoring BUT your issue is NullPointerException? What is exactly your question?

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)blackView.getLayoutParams();
    float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int dpAsPixels = (int) (-16*scale + 0.5f);
    params.rightMargin = dpAsPixels;
    params.leftMargin = dpAsPixels;
    params.bottomMargin = dpAsPixels;
    blackView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Set in your xml layout file at `RelativeLayout`: `android:clipToPadding="false"`

Comment: okay but I want to keep padding for other views I have in this activity

Comment: Then try to set negative padding. Convert 16dp it px.

Comment: I need to set negative margins but not sure how to do that?, see edit

Answer (score 0):

A better and cleaner solution to get padding in dp instead of pixel is the following.

You have to store the padding in resource files (i.e. `dimens.xml`), so you can simply call:

```
int padding = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.padding);
```

It does the conversion for you. Then you can set the padding to your desired view, for example:

```
mPicImageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
```